# Calculation on 2 arrays with for loop

Tags: arrays, vba

I am trying to perform a calculation on 2 arrays and then display the result in the immediate window however i get an error stating

> Compile error: For Each control variable must be Variant or Object

Both arrays appear to be variants - so i am not sure what i am doing wrong

```
Sub Main()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'declarations
Dim kr As Double
Dim arr As Variant
Dim varry As Variant
Dim x As Double
Dim y As Double

'declration of the 2 arrays
arr = range("ADB3:ADE3").Value
varry = range("ADB4:ADE4").Value

'nested for each loop taking each cell and tring to carry out formula
For Each x In arr
For Each y In varry

kr = ((x - y)) ^ 2 ^ 0.5 'formula taking the x from arr and the y from varry

Next varry
Next arr

'print answer
Debug.Print kr
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You can save Excel ranges only to `Variant` type arrays and you either convert this variant array to `Double` and operate on `Double`, or respect `Variant` type. Now your code says: For each banana in apple_basket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "control variable" in the error message `Compile error: For Each control variable must be Variant or Object` refers to the variable immediately after the `For` and not to the array that you are iterating over.

In `For Each x In arr` the control variable is `x`, which isn't a `Variant`. Declare it to be a variant and the problem disappears.

Alternatively, use something like:

```
Dim i As Long
'...
For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    x = arr(i)
    'etc.
```

Comment: The latter of which is a more effcient method for looping the array in this case.

Comment: "Declare it to be a variant and the problem disappears." perfect i didnt spot that

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to use `.Cells` and not `.Value`

```
'declration of the 2 arrays
arr = Range("ADB3:ADE3").Cells
varry = Range("ADB4:ADE4").Cells

'nested for each loop taking each cell and tring to carry out formula
For Each x In arr
For Each y In varry

kr = ((x - y)) ^ 2 ^ 0.5 'formula taking the x from arr and the y from varry

Next varry
Next arr
```

Comment: No need for `.Cells`